# SSL Certificate to Third Party Embedded Video

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, video.js

I'm embedding videos from another website which does not have an SSL certificate, because of this when the page that contains the video (with the source from another website) loads my website shows up as insecure as well, even tho I have a certificate, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "workaround". You need to make sure all resources are HTTPS. Browsers have given some leeway for video in some circumstances as "passive content" in the past and didn't show warnings, but they're getting stricter now for all requests.

Comment: @misterbean not sure but if you proxy the external resource you should get a workaround on this issue. Even if it is not a good idea at all

Comment: Given the tags I interpret the question to be asking for a client side workaround. Putting a HTTPS enabled proxy or CDN distro in front of the HTTP server would achieve delivering the content over HTTPS which is what's needed.